# What is the best way to not have DependencyProperties conflict with actual properties?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I find that when I make Dependency Properties, most of them **conflict** with names of properties in the UserControl, e.g Background, Width, etc. so my strategy is to **prefix all of my custom properties with "The"** so I have, e.g.

- TheBackground
- TheWidth

etc.

I tried using the "new" keyword which gets rid of the warning, but that leads to conflicts at runtime.

**Has anyone come upon better naming strategies for DependencyProperties in custom user controls?**

```
public partial class SmartForm : UserControl
{
    public SmartForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        TheBackground = "#FFD700";
    }

    #region DependencyProperty: TheBackground
    public string TheBackground
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TheBackgroundProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TheBackgroundProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TheBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TheBackground", typeof(string), typeof(SmartForm),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your UserControl has a background property, why do you have to add another one?

What is this new background a background for?  "The"?  No?  Then what background does it control?

Finish this sentence:  "This is the background color for the XXXX control."

The property name should now be XXXXBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want a override??

In my case I don't put Width as a DepedencyProperty

in my custom control I have:

```
    public double Width
    {
        get
        {
            if (_backgroundImage != null)
                return _backgroundImage.Width;
            else
                return double.NaN;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_backgroundImage != null)
                _backgroundImage.Width = value;
        }
    }
```

The compiler shows me a warning but everything seems to work.